# Haskell algebraic data type pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I have the following:

```
data Alpha a = Beta a [Alpha a]
val = Beta 1 [Beta 2 [], Beta 5 [Beta 7 []]]
```

I'm trying to define a function that will move over a val of type Alpha Int and sum it. My desired approach is to extract all the Ints and then sum the resulting list, but I am struggling to extract all the Ints as I don't know what to do with the recursion...

a slight attempt:

```
checkAlpha :: Alpha Int -> [Int]
checkAlpha (Beta a []) = [a]
checkAlpha (Beta a b) = [a] ++ (map checkAlpha b)
```

Obviously this doesn't quite work but I can't see a solution in sight.

Comment: In your function, `b` has type `[Alpha Int]`. Mapping `checkAlpha` over this list gives you `[[Int]]`, but your signature says you want to return `[Int]`. That's why you have to "collapse" the list into one layer - i.e. `(concat .) . map` also known as `concatMap`.

Comment: the minimal fix is to insert `concat $` between `(` and `map checkAlpha b)` in your code, to flatten one level off of the list of lists. Then you notice that the first clause is an instance of the second, because `map _ [] === []`. Then you replace `[a]++` with `a:` to arrive at Daniel's solution. So you were really close. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you used

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

instead of `map`, it would work and be elegant enough.

You don't need to treat the case of an empty list as second component specially,

```
checkAlpha :: Alpha a -> [a]
checkAlpha (Beta a alphas) = a : concatMap checkAlpha alphas
```

does what you want, and is independent of the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html) instead of `Alpha`, which has many handy operations:

```
> flatten $ Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 5 [Node 7 []]]
[1,2,5,7]
```